# VSCode not able to build a simple getting started application

Tags: visual-studio-code

- http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html
- Installed Node
- Installed Yo
- yo aspent
- pick the web application
- dnu update
- dun build failed with spectacular 2400 odd errors
- open the vsCode as we can issue a command on the top that did not work failed and complained omni sharp is not working.
- dun went with beta version 1.0.0.4
- some where i saw depends on mono downloaded mono installed it.
- re-open VSCode and still fails to run with the following error message

error from the vscode

> [INFO] Starting OmniSharp at '/Users/bvn/TestApplication'...
>
> [INFO] Started OmniSharp from '/Users/bvn/Downloads/Visual Studio
>   Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/jrieken.vscode-omnisharp/bin/omnisharp'
>   with process id 2775...
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Startup] Omnisharp server running using stdio
>   at location '/Users/bvn/TestApplication' on host 2765.
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DnxPaths] Using runtime
>   '/Users/bvn/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1'.
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DnxProjectSystem] Scanning
>   '/Users/bvn/TestApplication' for DNX projects
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DnxProjectSystem] Found project
>   '/Users/bvn/TestApplication/project.json'.
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DesignTimeHostManager] Listening on port
>   57325
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DesignTimeHostManager] Process ID 2784
>
> [ERROR:OmniSharp.Dnx.DesignTimeHostManager] Failed to launch
>   DesignTimeHost in a timely fashion.
>
> [ERROR] Error: Failed to start OmniSharp
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DesignTimeHostManager] Client accepted
>   127.0.0.1:57325

Comment: I am having similar problem:  [ERROR:OmniSharp.Dnx.DesignTimeHostManager] Failed to launch DesignTimeHost in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I **manually** installed OmniSharp into VS Code. I used the steps in [this link](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1028#issuecomment-268663994) to help point me in the right direction. After some tinkering, I got everything working in both OmniSharp  within VS Code and the dotnet core debugger integration. The link above implicitly suggests putting files in the `.bin\omnisharp\` folder (note the `.` prefixing `bin`) but, that didn't work... it worked when I put files in the `bin\omnisharp\` folder.

I'm running Windows 10 64bit and .Net Core SDK/CLI v1.0.4 with VSCode v1.14.2. Here are the steps:

1. Install OmniSharp in VSCode and then close VSCode
2. If it does not already exist, create `bin\omnisharp` and `.debugger` folders under `%userprofile%\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.11.0\`
3. In the `runtimeDependencies` section of this [packages.json](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/v1.11.0/package.json), download the zip files for `OmniSharp (.NET 4.6 / x64)` and for `.NET Core Debugger (Windows / x64)`
4. Unzip `omnisharp-win-x64-<version>.zip` into `%userprofile%\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.11.0\bin\omnisharp\`
5. Unzip `coreclr-debug-win7-x64.zip` into `%userprofile%\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.11.0\.debugger\`
6. Launch VSCode and run thru a simple Hello World dotnet core example... everything should work.

I hope the info helps. :)